# Hazelcast - strategy/algorithm for associating lock keys with map values for lock monitoring?

Tags: java, locking, distributed-computing, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I have a requirement that I could not find a solution using hazelcast IMap and ILock constructs.

I need to keep track of all locks acquired over a distributed map ( locks acquired after succesfull  IMap.tryLock(K key) call) . 
Every  successfully acquired lock must be associated/paired with a custom object in the map for tracking. (These custom objects contain application specific locker info for monitoring purposes.)
What I want is ,  when a lock is successfully acquired, the associated custom object related to the lock must automatically put to the map atomically.
And when the lock is released, the associated custom object related to the lock must automatically be evicted atomically .

In other words, I want to keep track of the locker info for all non released locks correctly.

My first attempt/tendency is to implement a lock utility method like below:

```
public boolean tryLockUtilMethod(String key, long maxTimeToWaitForTheLockInMilis) {
        boolean isLockAcquired = false;
        try {
            isLockAcquired = IMap.tryLock(key, maxTimeToWaitForTheLockInMilis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ...
        }

        if (isLockAcquired) {
            putLockInfoToMapAfterLockAcquire(key);

        }
    }
```

and an unlock utility method as below:

```
public void unlockUtilMethod(String key) {

            boolean isUnlockSuccess = false;

            try {
                IMap.unlock(key);
                isUnlockSuccess = true;
            } catch (IllegalMonitorStateException e) {
                // current thread does not hold the lock
                ...
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ...
            }

            if (isUnlockSuccess) {
                removeLockInfoAfterUnlockSuccess(key);
            }
        }
```

Apparently this approach is prone to errors because lock acquire/release operations and subsequent map put (in sample code putLockInfoToMapAfterLockAcquire method) / remove (in sample code removeLockInfoAfterUnlockSuccess method)  operations are not atomic...

I could not figure out a solution using hazelcast concurrent constructs.

What is the correct way to keep lock related info and ensure that they are synch with the locks? Did not anyone have a similar requirement before?

Any guidance is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no direct support on the API level for traversing or getting info about locks which obtained from Imap interface.So I think your way of doing it by yourself is correct. And for syncing lock info and lock you can use [hazelcast transactions.](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.5/manual/html/transactions.html)